# Windows Batch GEQ not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

I am trying to use GEQ (Greater than, or equal) in a Windows Batch script.
I have an IF clause testing for

```
if %count% GEQ 10
```

while counting %count% one up each pass. I had expected the condition to be true after ten passes. However, after running two times, the condition is true, while %count% is 2.

If I replace GEQ with ==, it works as expected, displays the number of passes up to ten and quits. I really don't understand where my error in thinking is, at this point. Please give me a heads-up.

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CLS

ECHO.
SET /a max = 10
ECHO This should run %max% times:

:REPEAT
set /a count = "%count%"+1
ECHO Test %count%

IF "%count%" GEQ "%max%" (
    GOTO :QUIT
) ELSE (
    GOTO :REPEAT
)

:QUIT
ECHO.
ECHO Done.
```

Comment: If you want to compare numbers, do not include quotes in the `if` clause, else you will be using strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF "%count%" GEQ "%max%" (
```

by using the quotes, you force `if` to compare strings, not numbers, so `2` is bigger than `19514`

Instead write:

```
IF %count% GEQ %max% (
```

Comment: I understand that using Strings for comparison at this point does not make sense. However I don't understand why ”2" is bigger than "19514", because the second string is both bigger converted to int as well as longer. It is bigger in every aspect.

Comment: No, it's not. String comparison starts at the first character. `2` is "bigger" than `1`. That's it. If the first characters are equal, _then_ it compares the second letter and so on. There is no check on the string length.

Comment: Oh, I didn't thought it really uses lexicographical comparison. Thanks for the clarification!